# Enabling 'linked' unit files in Systemd

Tags: linux, systemd

I am still getting to grips with systemd and have run into something. It's not so much a problem, but I would like to learn more about the way this is. I could not find any reference to this elsewhere.

First off, I understand that custom unit files for services should go in `/etc/systemd/system`. However, it would be nice for management of our servers if the unit files could be located elsewhere.

In the documentation, I saw that you may 'link' unit files like so:

```
systemctl link /path/to/servicename.service
```

This will create a link to the above in `/etc/systemd/system`. You are now able to start/stop this service. On the surface, this seemed like a good way for us to manage our services.

However, trying to enable such a 'linked' unit file results in failure:

```
root@test1:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl link /root/myservice.service 
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service to /root/myservice.service.

root@test1:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status myservice.service 
 * myservice.service - My Test Service
     Loaded: loaded (/root/myservice.service; linked; vendor preset: enabled)

root@test1:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl enable myservice.service
Failed to execute operation: No such file or directory
```

Using the exact same unit file, but copied in to `/etc/systemd/system` instead of linked in, you get:

```
root@test1:/etc/systemd/system# cp -p /root/myservice.service .

root@test1:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl daemon-reload 

root@test1:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl status myservice.service 
 * myservice.service - My Test Service
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myservice.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)

root@test1:/etc/systemd/system# systemctl enable myservice.service
Created symlink from /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/myservice.service to /etc/systemd/system/myservice.service.
```

From this, it seems that it is not possible to enable linked in unit files to be called at system startup.

If this is the case, what is the point of the 'link' functionality? From the docs, it says:

> link FILENAME
>
> Link a unit file that is not in the unit file search paths into the unit file search path. This requires an absolute path to a unit file. The effect of this can be undone with disable. The effect of this command is that a unit file is available for start and other commands although it is not installed directly in the unit search path.

Answer (score 21):

The man page is misleading.

<s>`systemctl link /root/myservice.service`</s>

```
systemctl enable /root/myservice.service
```

The first makes it possible for you to do `systemctl start myservice`. The second makes it possible for `myservice` to be started automatically (which, as @Julien pointed out, automatically adds the `link`).

I think... I've been trying to wrap my head around this all day.

Comment: note that `systemctl enable` will also do `systemctl link`, so no need to type the 2 commands ;-)

Comment: @Julien  Oh, where we you when I wrote this last year :-)  I think I finally realized that last month!

Comment: I think very few people know about this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

When enabling a service from another path than the default paths you should use the full path. Enable will also create the link for you:

```
systemctl enable /root/myservice.service
```

Once enabled you can start/stop/status with the service name

```
systemctl start myservice
```

A few caveats here:

- you can't enable a service file that is in itself already a link
- make sure the path is on the same mounted disk. If it is not, systemd will not be able to load the service unit files on boot because the disk will not be mounted yet and the files will not be found. (see [Systemd linked unit files on mounted disk fail to load](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291085/systemd-linked-unit-files-on-mounted-disk-fail-to-load?rq=1))
- due to a bug in systemd you can't enable instances from a unit file that is in a non standard path (see https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/661)