# Can I mount a drive before systemd-sysv-generator runs?

Tags: mount, systemd, initramfs

I am in the process of upgrading a sysv-based system to systemd (CentOS 6 -> 7), and I would like to rely on `systemd-sysv-generator` to run some of services that still have their scripts under /etc/init.d.

The problem is, some of the files under /etc/init.d are actually soft links to files on a secondary partition.

It looks like this partition is not yet mounted when `systemd-sysv-generator` runs, and all I see in the log is a bunch of "no such file or directory" errors from the generator script. Systemd documentation says that the generators run "[very early at bootup](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.generator.html)", and the processing of /etc/fstab happens much later.

I think what I need to do is somehow make initramfs or the kernel mount the secondary drive, but I don't know if that's possible. The responses for [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/798230/588) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17895102/7581) questions are not very encouraging, and seem to suggest that this is at the very least an unorthodox approach.

Another option might be to re-run the generator after the drive has been mounted, but I don't know how to do that, and whether it will be "too late", so to speak, and the services will get created but not started.

What should I do?

EDIT: To make it more concrete, let's say my root partition is at `/dev/sda1`, and I have a secondary partition at `/dev/sda2`, usually mounted as `/secondary`. `/etc/init.d/myservice` is a symbolic link to `/secondary/myservice`. This used to work fine, but stopped working under systemd for the reasons mentioned.

Comment: Related questions are https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425487/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/90723/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332747/ , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/ , and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236953/ .

Answer (score 1):

I would take the time to go ahead and do a one-time creation of proper `systemd` ".service" files for your legacy services. This will simplify your system overall, solving your boot order problem and eliminating the sysV->systemd translation later.

If your legacy services are provided by a third party, you may find that they have published `systemd` .service files for newer versions which you can likely easily adapt for the older versions you are running.

---

Another option is to simply copy the init scripts from the second partition to the boot partition. Add a comment to the files to remind future admins to copy them to the second location if they make changes.

Answer (score 0):

[Force systemd mounting some partititions before anything](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399169/force-systemd-mounting-some-partititions-before-anything?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment712809_399169)

> It would work if you treated your [secondary filesystem] like `usr`, i.e. mount it in the initramfs. Obviously this will require the initramfs to set up networking. The initramfs transition is equivalent to a daemon-reload, but you're not introducing one of those at a new point. `dracut` has specific support for mounting additional filesystems. ... I would specifically recommend using the mount option `x-initrd.mount` in fstab to mark the mount, as systemd also applies some special handling in this case.